# Insufficient Priviliges to access the User related Contact(Lookup) record

Tags: administration, security, sharing, permissions, profile

If i am having a User as a OverageHighVolumeCustomerPortal profile, it contains the Contact Lookup field. If i clicks the Contact Lookup then it throws the error like this:

> Insufficient Privileges You do not have the level of access necessary
>   to perform the operation you requested. Please contact the owner of
>   the record or your administrator if access is necessary.

I check all profile access level OWD,fieldsecurity,Object settings,Systempermissions everything is fine but it throw the error like this it doesn't it show the user related contact record.How to resolve this one?

Regards
Venkat

Comment: Maybe a standard Contact page was overriden with a Visualforce page and you have no access to that page?

Comment: Might be sharing-related. Can you follow the steps I've described in http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23675/case-assignment-insufficient-privileges ?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @mastOr, i assign the visualforce page&apex class access for the profile but it shows the same issue..

Comment: Thanks for your reply @eyescream , am use to the view the user related contact record through Systemadministrator,here for BusinessAccount it show the Contact record but the User related with PersonAccount record is getting some issues..Is any other ways to resolve this..

Answer (score 1):

So it's not a real contact, it's a person account (means you have Contact OWD set to "Controlled by parent")...

Still, same logic as described in [my comment](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/23675/case-assignment-insufficient-privileges) applies - click the `[Sharing]` button, expand the list and check if that user is present on the list for that record.

If he isn't - you'll have to fix sharing by doing any of these:

- changing OWD for Accounts to Public Read Only or better
- creating a sharing rule
- making him owner of that person account
- adding an entry in AccountShare table (in UI it's under the Sharing button) or making him an Account Team Member
- if the view page is overridden with visualforce page + controller - you could try using "without sharing" in the class definition.

Pick carefully, the first 3 solutions can have huge impact on your organization's data visibility.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @eyescream , i am admin user i want to see the  personcontact which is assoicated with customer portal user,i click on that personaccount record and click on the sharing button and i can see the admin userid in the Expand list..

Comment: Of course you will be there. But is **that** user (the one that is getting the insufficient priviledges error) there?

Comment: Thanks @eyescream ,i have another DevSandbox in there Expand list of Personaccount not have the Portaluser name that DevSandbox is working fine. In FullSandbox not only one user every Customer Portal Users(PersonAccount) having the same problem..
can you kindly help on this..

Comment: Are you sure he's not there by hitting "more rows per page" or filters on first letter of the name? Are organization-wide defaults, sharing rules etc same across these 2 sandboxes? The VF page that shows contacts is with same "with/without sharing" access modifier? What if you take that user and try to go non-overridden page: `/{contactId}?nooverride=1`? Is he logged in to the portal? And assigned to that account (https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=contacts_customer_portal.htm&language=en_US). Running out of ideas here ;)

Comment: Thanks @eyescream, Both sandbox organization-wide defaults, sharing rules are same.                                    What if you take that user and try to go non-overridden page: /{contactId}?nooverride=1? Is he logged in to the portal?yes he logged in.                                                        But last two days getting some problem to view the PersonAccount record..  kindly help on this ,Is there any other possible ways to resolve..

Comment: Then check setup audit trail, maybe somebody modified the VF page. Maybe the critical update for unescaped HTML markup was activated?